# Импорт дампа в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Как это сделать? Открыл в командной строке "`С:\Program and Files\PostgreSQL\8.4\bin\psql.exe`", а что дальше не помню, в памяти что-то болтается, имя юзера postgres имя дампа db.sql < а дальше не помню.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. По хорошему сначала удалить целевую базу, даже если таковой нет - перестраховаться от ошибок в процессе нужно.

   Сразу для объяснения:

   `-h` - это адрес сервера, 
   `-p` - это порт,
   `-U` - имя пользователя. Пароль будет запрошен при последующих действиях,
   `-e` - указание имени базы,
   `-E` - кодировка базы, встречается и UTF8, и CP1251,
   `-O` - владелец базы,
   `-i` - вывод всех сообщений в процессе импорта базы,
   `-d` - указание базы для импорта,
   `-v` - указание файла дампа

   `"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\8.4\\bin\\dropdb.exe" -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -e ВашаБаза`
2. Затем создаем пустую целевую базу:

   `"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\8.4\\bin\\createdb.exe" -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -E UTF8 -O postgres ВашаБаза`
3. Ну и импортируем дамп:

   `"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\8.4\\bin\\pg_restore.exe" -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d ВашаБаза -v "d:\\backup.backup"`

Answer (score 2):

```
psql dbname < db.sql
```

В документации смотрите подробнее http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup.html

Comment: Ок прочитаю,пробовал с \i тоже нормально,но оказывается у меня на базу стоит пароль)

Answer (score 0):

pgdump и pgrestore